# Remove Control Return and merge lines in one text file and limit number of characters

Tags: sed, awk, text, tr

I wan to remove Control Return and merge lines in one text file and limit number of characters

**input.txt** containing:

```
comment 1
comment 2 
...
comment n
```

**output.txt** should one strings:

```
comment 1 comment 2 ... commnet n
```

BUT the *ouput.txt* should be limited to i.e. 32 of characters:

```
comment 1 comment 2 comment 3 co
```

Can I use sed, awk tr or somthing else?

Comment: By `32 characters` you mean each line should not be more than `32 characters, right?

Comment: Do you really mean *carriage return* or rather *newline*, which is the usual line break in the unix world?

Answer (score 1):

```sh
head -c 32 input.txt | tr '\n' ' ' > output.txt
```

- `head -c 32` discards all but the first 32 bytes.
- `tr '\n' ' '` replaces all newline characters with space characters.

If you want to limit *characters* instead of *bytes* in case of multi-byte character encodings you can use `grep` instead:

```sh
tr '\n' ' ' < input.txt | grep -oEe '^.{,32}' > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk shall be fine. One way is:

```
$ echo -n "comment 1\rcomment 2\r...\rcomment n\r" > input.txt
$ cat input.txt | awk -v FS="" -v RS="" '{for (i=1;i<=32;i++) printf ($i == "\r")? "" : $i}' > output.txt
$ cat output.txt 
comment 1comment 2...comment
```

Explanation: by default awk processes input line-by-line, with single line called *record*; every line processed column-by-column, with single column called *field*. Every *field* is referred by variables starting with 1, e.g. $1, $2, $3…

So you change the default behavior by setting **F**ield **S**eparator to `""`, causing awk to process stuff character-by-character. Then you set **R**ecord **S**eparator to `""` so you can refer to characters of all text at once *(i.e. without writing a code to handle stuff line-by-line)*.

Finally, you can easily operate on characters, so you loop over the fields *(i.e. characters)*, and print only when the character is not a carriage return.

Comment: Why all these carriage-return characters (`\r`) in the input? The escape sequence for newline characters is `\n`.

Comment: @DavidFoerster OP asked for carriage return, idk why.

Comment: Hmm… you're right. But I think they actually meant line break/newline characters.

Comment: @DavidFoerster well, `\r` is easy to replace with `\n`, so it's not a big deal. But FTR, my original answer have used `\n` ☺ But then I noticed OP's "Control Return" with first letters suspiciously similar to CR, and quickly replaced it. This edit is not saved because I did it within the 5 minutes timeout.

Answer (score 0):

```
tr '\n' ' ' < in.txt | cut -c -32
```

- `tr '\n' ' '`: remove new lines from input text
- `cut -c -32`: limit the output to 32 characters